# modify / beautify / edit base64 images in Java

Tags: java, base64, itext

I am using base64 as signatures in my project and I need to modify the existing base64 to add some lines and designs. How do we do that?

[image: sign right now]
[[image: target sign (my source image will be inside instead of the text)]]

Comment: Base64 is not an image format but just encoding. Decode the base64 string to the original image format, manipulate the image and reencode it to base64.

Comment: Also you have tagged your question [tag:itext]. This points towards PDF as format. And your screenshot looks like from a PDF with signatures applied using DocuSign. So, is this about changing signature stroke images?

Comment: @mkl thanks for replying. I was previously using com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSignatureAppearance to add some metadata about signatures. that is why i tagged iText. but i now feel, as jps suggested, i should first perform modifications and then just provide the updated image to iText.

Comment: just curious, do u think that the design that I've provided is achievable by the options provided in PdfSignatureAppearance ? @mkl

Comment: *"do u think that the design that I've provided is achievable by the options provided in PdfSignatureAppearance"* - Well, it isn't the default design created by `PdfSignatureAppearance`. But as you can provide arbitrary own designs (see [Digital Signing with iText 7 / Part IV - Appearances](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/digital-signing-with-itext-7/part-iv-appearances)), it's achievable.

Comment: If there's a question about DocuSign - please update the question. Not clear how this is related to DocuSign except the image, so not sure how to help.

Comment: nothing except the design @InbarGazit, removing the docusignapi tag. couldnt find a design tag so added this one.